# ran cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I am trying to make a code that when I run an application, there is a random image, and when I click on it, it shows a different random image, but I get errors and I only have 1 day experience and Java language.

Please help.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            int[] photos={R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};

            ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

            Random rnd=new Random();
★1         int i=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
            image.setImageResource(photos[i]);
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
★2               int k=ran.nextInt(photos.length);
★3               image.setImageResource(photos[k]);
                }
            }
            );


        }
```

I added ★'s to show you where the errors are.

★1 "ran cannot be resolved"
★2 "Cannot refer to a non-final variable photos inside an inner class defined in a different method"
"ran cannot be resolved"
★3 "Cannot refer to a non-final variable image inside an inner class defined in a different method"
"Cannot refer to a non-final variable photos inside an inner class defined in a different method"

I tried refreshing and also did ctrl+shift+o, can't figure out where the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
        Random rnd=new Random();
```

to

```
        final Random ran=new Random();
```

Also, change

```
        int[] photos=...;
        ImageView image=...;
```

to

```
        final int[] photos=...;
        final ImageView image=...;
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the ran error.
But the "refer to a non-final variable" still lies unfixed, but I'm sure It'll be figured out!

Comment: missing the final modifier on the 'rnd' variable too to be complete

Answer (score 4):

1) You've declared a variable `rnd`, but then you're trying to refer to it as `ran`. You need to be consistent.

2 and 3) Both `photos` and `rnd` would need to be declared as `final` variables because you're using them in an anonymous inner class.

The business about local variables being final when they're used within an anonymous inner class is basically because of the way that anonymous inner classes work. Basically when you construct an instance, it passes the local variable values into the (generated) constructor for the anonymous inner class, which keeps copies of those variables for when they're used later. By restricting the variables to `final` ones, it avoids situations where the variable could be changed either in the method or in the anonymous inner class, with those changes not being seen in the other context.

Comment: You missed the 'image' variable that need to be final too.

Comment: Oh, thank you.

Now the last error I have is in this line:
final image.setImageResource(photos[k]);
it says there is a "Syntax error on token(s), misplace construct(s)".
I will search the solution for that, thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

1) I guess you meant  `rnd.nextInt(...`   ('rnd',  not 'ran')

2) add the `final` modifier to the `photos` and `rnd` variable to fix this :

```
final int[] photos={R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};
```

3) same on the image view image:

```
final ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
```